# Rails ActionController::MethodNotAllowed causes WSOD in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I've got a RESTful resource (let's say `posts`) that excludes the `index` action. When I go to `/posts`, `ActionController::MethodNotAllowed` is raised because `GET` requests at that URL have been excluded. That much makes sense.

The problem is that in the production environment, that URL just generates a white screen in the browser. I can see `ActionController::MethodNotAllowed` being raised in the production log. I would expect that this would also cause a `404` or `500` error so that the error pages in the `public` directory would serve a pretty error page to the client.

Does this cause a different HTTP status code? How can I handle this?

Comment: WSOD. HAdn't heard that before.

Comment: @Matchu http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_screen_of_death

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive about what the error might be, but you should get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check what the HTTP response code coming back is.

To get around the issue, you could do one of two things:

1. Don't disallow that page in the routes, but have the only code in that method do a redirect to an appropriate page.
2. Add a custom route that overrides `GET /posts`, which points to your desired controller.

Comment: Checking the response code with Firebug (technically the Web Inspector in my case) did the trick. The status code was 405 (Method Not Allowed, very fitting!) so I just made a 405 error page in the public directory. Thank you!